# Map Service Requests Errors in Logs

Tags: arcgis-server

In arc gis for server 10.2 I have deleted some map services. But in the server logs it shows the following messages regularly even though the services are not in use anymore. I deleted the services through server manager

SEVERE

29 Apr 2015 13:25:08

Unable to process request. Service (service name would be here) not found

### Rest

WARNING

29 Apr 2015 13:25:08

Error getting service.

Rest

Could anyone suggest why it may be logging these errors regularly?

Comment: Just curious, was this a cached map service?

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't a cached map service

Answer (score 1):

Is some application trying to access the deleted service? For example: if I try calling a deleted map service I get the following logs:

[image]

Comment: I've checked to see if any applications are trying to access the services like you mention above. From what I can tell there are no applications that should be using these services anymore. Before I deleted the services I made sure that all applications that were using them were removed. Sometimes the errors keeping repeating for a long time then stop then start again. Is there anything else that could be calling these services besides applications? 

For example a process within ArcGIS for server.

Comment: If you haven't already, you could turn on the other Logs columns like machine, code, user name you might be able to drill down on it...For instance, I just typed a deleted service into a browser and the machine column identified me... If it is some stray service in an app I think it would bring back that app in the username columnn, etc.. And also set log filter to Verbose